# Objective-C Special Index for a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a program in Cocoa that I would like to load different texts onto a Textfield. That's not the hard part. The problem I have now is that I have several paragraphs of text. I would like to, like in human language, give each paragraph a name (indexing???). For example, Paragraph1 for the 1st paragraph and Paragraph2 for the 2nd paragraph. Then I would like to call them out by their names. At first I was thinking of setValueForKey but then the "key" is unchangeable since it is a property. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/)

```
NSMutableDictionary *mParagraphs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1st paragraph ", @"Paragraph1",@"2nd paragraph ",@"Paragraph2",nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [mParagraphs objectForKey:@"Paragraph1"]);
```